# How to deal with attempt of caching data from a db (Redshift) to Spark?

Tags: pyspark, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I have a scenario where there is an attempt to `df.persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK_DESER)` some tables from db, in my case Redshift, before to run different queries. Tables can have from a few hundreds million to a few billion records. I am using Glue/Jobs at the moment, and no matter how many DPU I use, it takes a very long time to do it (if does not fail before). Is there any way to speed up the process?

Comment: `UNLOAD` the tables from Redshift and then read from S3? Reading billions of rows via JDBC would be quite slow unless reading in parallel.

Comment: Here are some things that you can try - 
1) check how much time its taking on redshift cluster. 
2)Look at the run time stats of the glue job and understand how many connections its creating to understand the how many jdbs threads are running in parallel.
3) try to optimize the redshift cluster workflod

Comment: I have added `"numPartitions":"32"` to the jdbc connection and set to 32 worker with G2X type so I guess I have one executor per partition

Comment: there could be skewness in the data so that would result in few threads getting stalled and running for longer. to avoid that you can use partitionColumn, lowerBound, and upperBound

Comment: true, my problem is that I have a "good" column to use for partitioning